# jOOQ: fetchInto with fieldsRow() returns null for Record object but not for POJOs

Tags: java, jooq

I recently ran into some unexpected jOOQ behaviour. I'd written a query where I was mixing fetching into jOOQ-generated POJOs and jOOQ generated Record classes. A colleague correctly pointed out that I should be consistent and use just Record or just POJO classes, so I updated my query to fetch Record objects instead.

However, I updated the `fetchInto` call to point to a Record class instead of a POJO, and suddenly my previously-working and otherwise unchanged queries were returning Record objects where all fields were null!

Eventually I tried adjusting the select query and selected each relevant field individually, and then the relevant objects were populated correctly.

**Why does this behaviour happen?**

Code examples for each of the 3 scenarios:

`fieldsRow()` and fetching into a generated POJO, everything works as expected:

```
conf ->
    conf.dsl()
    .select(
        RUN.fieldsRow().as("run").convertFrom(r -> r.into(RunRecord.class)),
        RUN_PROGRESS
        .fieldsRow()
        .as("run_progress")
        .convertFrom(r -> r.into(RunProgressRecord.class)),
        multiset(
            select(REASON.fieldsRow()) <----- 
            .from(REASON)
            .where(REASON.RUN_ID.eq(RUN.ID)))
        .as("reasons")
        .convertFrom(r -> r.into(Reason.class)))   <---- 
    .from(RUN)
    .leftOuterJoin(RUN_PROGRESS)
    .on(RUN_PROGRESS.RUN_ID.eq(RUN.ID))
    .where(RUN.ID.eq(runId.getValue()))
    .fetch()
```

`fieldsRow()` and fetching into a generated Record class, all fields of the retrieved `ReasonRecord` objects are null!?!

```
conf ->
    conf.dsl()
    .select(
        RUN.fieldsRow().as("run").convertFrom(r -> r.into(RunRecord.class)),
        RUN_PROGRESS
        .fieldsRow()
        .as("run_progress")
        .convertFrom(r -> r.into(RunProgressRecord.class)),
        multiset(
            select(REASON.fieldsRow())
            .from(REASON)
            .where(REASON.RUN_ID.eq(RUN.ID)))
        .as("reasons")
        .convertFrom(r -> r.into(ReasonRecord.class)))   <---- 
    .from(RUN)
    .leftOuterJoin(RUN_PROGRESS)
    .on(RUN_PROGRESS.RUN_ID.eq(RUN.ID))
    .where(RUN.ID.eq(runId.getValue()))
    .fetch()
```

Selecting each `Reason` field individually, everything works as expected again:

```
conf ->
    conf.dsl()
    .select(
        RUN.fieldsRow().as("run").convertFrom(r -> r.into(RunRecord.class)),
        RUN_PROGRESS
        .fieldsRow()
        .as("run_progress")
        .convertFrom(r -> r.into(RunProgressRecord.class)),
        multiset(
            select(REASON.RUN_ID, REASON.REASON_)  <------
            .from(REASON)
            .where(REASON.RUN_ID.eq(RUN.ID)))
        .as("reasons")
        .convertFrom(r -> r.into(ReasonRecord.class)))
    .from(RUN)
    .leftOuterJoin(RUN_PROGRESS)
    .on(RUN_PROGRESS.RUN_ID.eq(RUN.ID))
    .where(RUN.ID.eq(runId.getValue()))
    .fetch()
```

Comment: The `REASON.fieldsRow()` failure from within the `MULTISET` might be a bug. Would you mind reporting it here? https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/new/choose

Answer (score 1):

#### A simpler solution

Assuming that `ReasonRecord` is the generated `TableRecord` for the `REASON` table, then starting from jOOQ 3.17, you can simply project the table reference itself:

```java
select(REASON)
.from(REASON)
.where(REASON.RUN_ID.eq(RUN.ID))
```

That way, you don't have to apply any ad-hoc conversion anymore to get a nested  `Result<ReasonRecord>`. (You might still keep it in order to turn the `Result<ReasonRecord>` into a `List<ReasonRecord>` if your typing makes this necessary...).

Likewise, you don't need to use `RUN.fieldsRow()` anymore. Just project `RUN`:

```java
conf.dsl()
    .select(
       RUN,
       RUN_PROGRESS,
       ...)
```

Comment: Ah, I was still on jOOQ 3.16, this is a much nicer way of expressing the same query. Thanks for the reply! (I believe that I do still need the ad-hoc conversion to turn the `Result<ReasonRecord>` into a `List<ReasonRecord>`)